# Confusion in JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  SELECT i.invoice_date inv, 
         i.invoice_id, 
         i.total_amount, 
         oi.invoice_date oi_inv, 
         oi.offline_invoice_number, 
         oi.invoice_amount 
    FROM ci_invoices i 
              LEFT JOIN ci_offline_invoice oi 
                        ON oi.customer_id = 9 
   WHERE i.customer_id = 9 
ORDER BY i.invoice_date 
   LIMIT 10
```

this query give the result

[image]

As you see in the screenshot i have only one row in the highlighted section and i want the result according to date:

```
2014-02-03
2014-01-16
2014-01-16
2014-01-16
2014-01-16
2014-01-16
..........
```

but i got the date `2014-02-03` every time(limit 10)

Comment: Please, provide more info on your tables. And it is also not clear, how you wanna order the results, by date only, or by datetime.

Comment: since you're joining on customerid = 9 it will return 1 row from `oi` table for each entry in `i` table

Comment: @MilenPavlov i am just near to resolve the problem, is there any way to short the data according to highest date? because it could be in `i` table or in `oi` table?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT i.invoice_date inv, 
         i.invoice_id, 
         i.total_amount, 
         oi.invoice_date oi_inv, 
         oi.offline_invoice_number, 
         oi.invoice_amount 
    FROM ci_invoices i 
              LEFT JOIN ci_offline_invoice oi 
                        ON oi.customer_id = i.customer_id
   WHERE i.customer_id = 9 
ORDER BY i.invoice_date 
   LIMIT 10
```

** Edit **

They are not the same thing.

Consider these queries:

```
SELECT i.invoice_date inv, 
         i.invoice_id, 
         i.total_amount, 
         oi.invoice_date oi_inv, 
         oi.offline_invoice_number, 
         oi.invoice_amount 
    FROM ci_invoices i 
              LEFT JOIN ci_offline_invoice oi 
                        ON oi.customer_id = i.customer_id
   WHERE i.customer_id = 9 
ORDER BY i.invoice_date 
   LIMIT 10
```

AND

```
SELECT i.invoice_date inv, 
         i.invoice_id, 
         i.total_amount, 
         oi.invoice_date oi_inv, 
         oi.offline_invoice_number, 
         oi.invoice_amount 
    FROM ci_invoices i 
              LEFT JOIN ci_offline_invoice oi 
                        ON oi.customer_id = 9 
   WHERE i.customer_id = 9 
ORDER BY i.invoice_date 
   LIMIT 10
```

> The first will return an ci_invoices and its lines, if any, for
>   customer_id =9.
>
> The second will return all ci_invoices, but only customer_id 9 will
>   have any lines associated with it.

On INNER JOINs they are interchangeable, and the optimizer will rearrange them at will.

On OUTER JOINs, they are not necessarily interchangeable, depending on which side of the join they depend on.

Comment: the same result i have got :(, is there any difference to `oi.customer_id = i.customer_id` instead of `oi.customer_id = 9` because it is same??

Comment: thanks for the information, i am just near to resolve the problem, is there any way to short the data according to highest date? because it could be in `i` table or in `oi` table? because `ORDER BY i.invoice_date ` is not working accordingly

Comment: I can't get your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the date too:

```
   SELECT i.invoice_date inv, 
             i.invoice_id, 
             i.total_amount, 
             oi.invoice_date oi_inv, 
             oi.offline_invoice_number, 
             oi.invoice_amount 
        FROM ci_invoices i 
                  LEFT JOIN  ci_offline_invoice oi 
                            ON oi.customer_id = 9 and date(i.invoice_date) = oi.invoice_date
       WHERE i.customer_id = 9 
    ORDER BY i.invoice_date 
       LIMIT 10
```

This should return only entries from the left table that have matching customer id and invoice date